# How to encode UTF inside an Encapsulated PostScript

Tags: vector-graphics, font-rendering

Twenty years ago I made a descriptive illustration program whose output was the industrial standard Encapsulated PostScript, which is also compatible with the LaTeX system. In order to write accented characters (a very important feature for Spanish texts), I created an ISOLatin1Encoding which was rather very simple.

```
/ISOLatin1Encoding where {
} {
    (ISOLatin1 does not exist, creating...) =
    /ISOLatin1Encoding StandardEncoding STARTDIFFENC
        144 /dotlessi /grave /acute /circumflex /tilde 
        /macron /breve /dotaccent /dieresis /.notdef /ring 
        /cedilla /.notdef /hungarumlaut /ogonek /caron /space 
        /exclamdown /cent /sterling /currency /yen /brokenbar 
        /section /dieresis /copyright /ordfeminine 
        /guillemotleft /logicalnot /hyphen /registered 
        /macron /degree /plusminus /twosuperior 
        /threesuperior /acute /mu /paragraph /periodcentered 
        /cedilla /onesuperior /ordmasculine /guillemotright 
        /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters /questiondown 
        /Agrave /Aacute /Acircumflex /Atilde /Adieresis 
        /Aring /AE /Ccedilla /Egrave /Eacute /Ecircumflex 
        /Edieresis /Igrave /Iacute /Icircumflex /Idieresis 
        /Eth /Ntilde /Ograve /Oacute /Ocircumflex /Otilde 
        /Odieresis /multiply /Oslash /Ugrave /Uacute 
        /Ucircumflex /Udieresis /Yacute /Thorn /germandbls 
        /agrave /aacute /acircumflex /atilde /adieresis 
        /aring /ae /ccedilla /egrave /eacute /ecircumflex 
        /edieresis /igrave /iacute /icircumflex /idieresis 
        /eth /ntilde /ograve /oacute /ocircumflex /otilde 
        /odieresis /divide /oslash /ugrave /uacute 
        /ucircumflex /udieresis /yacute /thorn /ydieresis
    ENDDIFFENC
}

/REENCODEFONT { % /Newfont NewEncoding /Oldfont
    findfont dup length 4 add dict
    begin
        { % forall
            1 index /FID ne 

            2 index /UniqueID ne and
            2 index /XUID ne and
            { def } { pop pop } ifelse
        } forall
        /Encoding exch def
        % defs for DPS
        /BitmapWidths false def
        /ExactSize 0 def
        /InBetweenSize 0 def
        /TransformedChar 0 def
        currentdict
    end
    definefont pop
} bind def

/ISOTimes-Roman ISOLatin1Encoding /Times-Roman REENCODEFONT
```

Nowadays Latin1 was replaced by UTF-8 and there is nothing I can do about it, it is currently supported by most operative systems. Is there a simple way to use UTF-8 in EPS files or I will have to create another code to reencoding?

Thank you in advance for any hints.